# How to change nodemon config directory?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

By default nodemon try to find `nodemon.json` config file in the project root directory right?
How can I prevent this default behavior?

Suppose I put this `nodemon.json` file in `src/config/` so, how should I configure nodemon to look for my own directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the nodemon documentation, I found the solution is very simple just by adding this to the script.
We have to add `--config` flag and then the directory.

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "node src/index.js",
   "dev": "nodemon --config src/config/nodemon.json src/index.js",
},
```

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation and [github page](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files):

> nodemon supports local and global configuration files. These are usually named nodemon.json and can be located in the current working directory or in your home directory. An alternative local configuration file can be specified with the --config  option.

Check out also the [extended sample](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md).